# WebSockets query fails with short heartbeat

Tags: websocket, python-multithreading, aiohttp

I have a Python server which serves some long-running queries for large amounts of data from a Postgres DB. The requests are served via WebSockets, and the server uses asyncio and aiohttp as the main framework.

In general, every request gets split into smaller chuncks, and each chunk has its subquery to the DB running in a separate thread.

In some cases, queries fail for no apparent reason, with the client complaining that connection has been closed on server side, and viceversa the server logging that the request was closed by the client.

After some trial and error, I found out that this can be mitigated by increasing the heartbeat of the WebSockets request:

```py
await aiohttp.ClientSession().ws_connect(
    self.url,
    heartbeat=60.0,  # was 20 seconds
    # ...
)
```

However I'd like to find a better way to handle this. Also, I'm not completely sure I understand why this is happening.

Someone suggested it's due to the GIL, with some CPU-bound task in another thread that might be monopolising things and freezing all the other threads. In which case, how can I make sure that whatever CPU-bound task is running does not starve the heartbeat?

Another issue I had was how to debug this. Since logs or debugging were a struggle, what would be a good strategy to pinpoint this or similar issues in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided code, but likely because heartbeat responses are only handled while iterating over the messages. Dupe of https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/discussions/7320#discussioncomment-6144209

In short, when reading from the websocket, if it's going to take a significant amount of time to handle the message, push the handling to another task, so the the loop can continue iterating. Failure to do so will result in ping calls not getting handled in a timely manner.